# How to rerender data in a javascript table orderd by a specific column

Tags: javascript, jquery

By javascript I generate rows for Agents in a table. every row represent an agent. after this I receive live data to update the columns. I have a column called (Calls) and i need to order the agents by calls (live update depending on received data) descending. example

```
agents ----- calls
Sam ---------13
Al  ---------12
Sara---------8
```

if Sara got the most data by time then she'll be the first.

```
agents -------calls
Sara----------15
Sam ----------13
Al------------12
```

and so on ..

this is my row rendering

```
var $agentRow = '<tr id="agentRow_' + agentId + '"><th scope="row">' + agentName + '</th><td class="calls" id="agentCalls_' + agentId + '">' + outTotalCalls +
            '</td><td class="minutes" id="agentMinutes_' + agentId + '">' +
            outCallMinutes + '</td>' +
            '<td class="averages" id="agentAverage_' + agentId + '">' + averageOutCallTime + '</td></tr>';

    //if $agentRow exists invoke setIncomingValuesToAgentsFields else append it to the table
    if ($('#agentRow_' + agentId).length) {
        setIncomingValuesToAgentsFields('#agentCalls_' + agentId, outTotalCalls);
        setIncomingValuesToAgentsFields('#agentMinutes_' + agentId, outCallMinutes);
        setIncomingValuesToAgentsFields('#agentAverage_' + agentId, averageOutCallTime);
    } else {
        $('#agentsTable').append($agentRow);
    }


function setIncomingValuesToAgentsFields(elementId, inComingValue) {
    var currentElementValue = 0;
    if ($(elementId).text() !== "") {
        currentElementValue = $(elementId).text();
        currentElementValue = parseFloat(currentElementValue);
        currentElementValue += inComingValue;
        $(elementId).text(currentElementValue);
    } else {
        $(elementId).text(currentElementValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look at this [plugin](http://fooplugins.com/footable-demos/) you can create something like [this](http://fooplugins.com/footable/demos/multiple-showcases.htm)

Comment: Looks good but I don't need click. This side will be displayed on a TV

Comment: simply call the function in [docs](http://fooplugins.com/footable/demos/sorting.htm#docs) at the end of ajax success. It's very simple. no need for clicks ...FYI mobile compatible too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the live sample of what you need. After 3 second Al calls become 14, and table rows will be sorted again.

```js
var agents = [
    { name: 'Sara', calls : 15 },
    { name: 'Sam',  calls : 13 },
    { name: 'Al',   calls : 12 }
];
    
function to_row(obj){
    var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    tr.data('obj', obj);
    $('<td>'+obj.name+'</td>').appendTo(tr);
    $('<td>'+obj.calls+'</td>').appendTo(tr);
    return tr;
}

function table_update(obj){
    $('#table tr').each(function(){        
        var t=$(this);
        var o=t.data('obj'); 
        if(o.name==obj.name){
            t.remove();
        };
        if(o.calls>obj.calls){
            to_row(obj).insertAfter(t);
        }
        return t.data('obj');
    })    
}

agents.sort(function(x,y){
    return y.calls - x.calls;
}).forEach(function(o){
    to_row(o).appendTo( $('#table') );
});

setTimeout(function(){
    table_update( { name: 'Al', calls : 14 } );
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you will be getting data from server using Ajax call . So If your having the result data in JSON object , then you can sort the data to find out which is having highest value . The follwing functon will help us to sort the data

```
sortTable:function (property,asc)
{
    sampleTableObject = sampleTableObject.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (asc) return (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : ((a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : 0);
        else return (b[property] > a[property]) ? 1 : ((b[property] < a[property]) ? -1 : 0);
    });     
}
```

**property** is the json object property (here it should be calls) based on which you need to sort .

Pass false to '**asc**' to sort in descending order.

Assign **sampleTableObject** with the **result json object** and call sortTable() . Then use the sorted object to build the table.

Comment: The data I get all in int/float, only the name is a string. Can I crate an object and pass it to this function? Or pass the property?

Comment: Is it JSON / text . Please post some sample data . If it's a json object it code replcae sampleTableObject with your object name and call this function to sort.

Comment: Thanks for help dude! I solve it with another solution but I'll consider the answer as a green one.